# tomcat manager deployment issue : war file name changeing after deployment

Tags: tomcat

When I was deploying any war file using tomcat manager console( WAR file to deploy option in console ).

using **uploading** war to console. The war name name is taking in console As c:/desktop/----

example : if the war file is "JAVA" after uploaded to console the war name changing to "C:/DesktopJAVA"

Please help any one on this.

Comment: Please provide more information about your Tomcat. (installation location, configuration, ...)

Comment: Hi Mickael,

Just I have did the deployment using chrome and it went with any problem.

when I using IE browser facing issue. It is a bug for tomcat version ?

version of tomcat : 8.0.36 we installed in server .